How to open usb webcam, device class 239
Before asking, I live in non-english region. So, I'm poor in English.
I tried to connect webcam camera with android application, using openCV.
But openCv can't find my webcam.
My sample app has usb host permission, camera permission. OpenCv initalize also success.
But VideoCapture can't find my camera.
DeviceClass of my webcam is 239(0xEF), not 0xF.
Do you have any opinion ?
Here's my full code of connection.
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val TAG = "MainActivity"

private lateinit var usbManager: UsbManager
private lateinit var device: UsbDevice
private lateinit var videoCapture: VideoCapture
private lateinit var surfaceView: SurfaceView
private lateinit var surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder


val ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "ACTION_USB_PERMISSION"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // SurfaceView 초기화
    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView)
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.holder
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
            // 비디오 스트리밍 시작
            startVideoStreaming()
        }

        override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {}

        override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
            stopVideoStreaming()
        }
    })

    usbManager = getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager

    val filter = IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)
    registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter)

    // USB 장치 검색
    discoverUsbDevices()
}

private fun discoverUsbDevices() {
    val deviceList = usbManager.deviceList
    for (usbDevice in deviceList.values) {
        if (usbDevice.deviceClass == 239) {
            device = usbDevice
            requestPermission(device)
        }
    }
}

private fun requestPermission(device: UsbDevice) {
    val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
}

private val usbReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION == intent?.action) {
            val usbDevice: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            if (usbDevice != null && intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                // 웹캠 초기화 및 스트리밍 시작
                startVideoStreaming()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun startVideoStreaming() {
    // OpenCV 초기화
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.e("OpenCV", "Initialization Failed")
        return
    }

    // VideoCapture 객체 생성, USB 카메라의 인덱스는 0으로 설정 (첫 번째 카메라)
    videoCapture = VideoCapture(0)

    Log.d(TAG, "startVideoStreaming: ${videoCapture.isOpened}")

    // 비디오 스트리밍을 위한 쓰레드 생성
    Thread {
        val frame = Mat()
        while (videoCapture.isOpened) {
            if (videoCapture.read(frame)) {
                // 프레임을 SurfaceView에 렌더링
                Log.d(TAG, "startVideoStreaming: ")
                renderFrame(frame)
            }
        }
    }.start()
}

private fun renderFrame(frame: Mat) {
    // 프레임을 Bitmap으로 변환
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame.cols(), frame.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    Utils.matToBitmap(frame, bitmap)

    // UI 스레드에서 SurfaceView에 비트맵 렌더링
    runOnUiThread {
        val canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas()
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
    }
}

private fun stopVideoStreaming() {
    videoCapture.release()
}

}

Can you access your USB camera through Android APIs?

@ChristophRackwitz Yes, UsbManager device list have webcam

What is the brand and model of the webcam?

@toyotaSupra Abko, korea company, maunfacturing hardware.
model name is "APC890w"
